# setcookie on click and selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to write a cookie when a visitor to my site clicks a link, and a "remember my choice" checkbox is selected. I'm new to cookies; what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Removed PHP tags, added javascript + jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would very advantageous to use jquery. Jquery cookie plugin is link below:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Code is here:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Sample app for your case.

http://jsfiddle.net/B3u7y/

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to do this. Check out this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Alternatively using jQuery (much better in my opinion), there is a [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) for this!

An example of the jQuery method using this plugin would be:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```